# Laravel create model already with the necessary relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to save a model in the database that needs to have some relationships already defined and I wanted to know if there's another way to do this.

The model I'm trying to save:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Download extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "tec_downloads";
    protected $primaryKey = "tdo_id";
    protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
    const CREATED_AT = "tdo_criado_em";
    const UPDATED_AT = "tdo_atualizado_em";
    protected $with = [
        "type",
        "status",
        "builder",
        "enterprise",
        "apartment",
        "house",
        "ticket",
        "requester"
    ];

    public function getIdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tdo_id;
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tdo_criado_em;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tdo_atualizado_em;
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DownloadType::class, "tdt_id", "tdt_id");
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DownloadStatus::class, "tds_id", "tds_id");
    }

    public function builder()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Builder::class, "con_id", "con_id");
    }

    public function enterprise()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Enterprise::class, "emp_id", "emp_id");
    }

    public function apartment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Apartment::class, "uni_id", "uni_id");
    }

    public function house()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(House::class, "cas_id", "cas_id");
    }

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ticket::class, "cha_id", "cha_id");
    }

    public function requester()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, "usr_id", "usr_id");
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "createdAt" => $this->createdAt,
            "updatedAt" => $this->updatedAt,
            "type" => $this->type,
            "status" => $this->status,
            "builder" => $this->builder,
            "enterprise" => $this->enterprise,
            "apartment" => $this->apartment,
            "house" => $this->house,
            "ticket" => $this->ticket,
            "requester" => $this->requester,
        ];
    }
}
```

At first I tried using the `setRelation` method to bind the non-nullable fields before using the save method, but it didn't work:

```php
$download = new Download();
$download->setRelation("type", DownloadType::findOrFail(DownloadType::TICKET));
$download->setRelation("status", DownloadStatus::findOrFail(DownloadStatus::REQUESTED));
$download->setRelation("builder", $ticket->enterprise->builder);
$download->setRelation("enterprise", $ticket->enterprise);
$download->setRelation("ticket", $ticket);
$download->setRelation("requester", User::findOrFail($requester));
$download->save();
```

This returns me the following error:

"Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tdt_id' cannot be null (SQL: update `tec_downloads_tipos` set `tdt_id` = ? where `tdt_id` = 3)"

And if I do this it works, but I want to know if this is the correct way to do this:

```php
$download = new Download();
$download->tdt_id = DownloadType::TICKET;
$download->tds_id = DownloadStatus::REQUESTED;
$download->con_id = $ticket->enterprise->builder->id;
$download->emp_id = $ticket->enterprise->id;
$download->cha_id = $ticket->id;
$download->usr_id = User::findOrFail($requester)->id;
$download->save();
```

Comment: Yes, the second way would be the way to create it. If `$requester` is a user ID, I don't know why you're using it to get the user, unless you're checking for failure (which can be done with a validation rule)

Answer (score 0):

When you save that $download model, the framework doesn't take into account the relations that you set. That's why your first approach fails.

Your second approach is totally fine. I personally prefer to use the [create](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#inserts) method.

If you are new to the framework, I suggest reading the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.